# Angular support/matturity for inheritance

Tags: angular, inheritance

I am wondering about the way we should use inheritance in Angular projects.

- Is is a good practice to use inheritance between services ?
- Is is a good practice to use inheritance between components ?
- What are the limits ?
- Why Angular official doc doesn't mention this subject ?

Comment: I don't think there is much that is Angular specific. Usually composition should be favored over inheritance.

Comment: this is so sad, a big loose in maintainability, composition and inheritance should have different use cases

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You're complaining about object oriented programming in general? As I said I don't think there is anything Angular specific. There are a few things with decorators that you have to consider. Not sure if this is still up-to-date https://medium.com/@amcdnl/inheritance-in-angular2-components-206a167fc259

Comment: You also can't use interfaces or polymorphism for dependency injection (if a class created by DI has a dependency, then exactly that class needs to be registered. You can use `{ provide SubClass: useClass: SuperClass }` though, but you need to explicitly provide the type used in the constructor parameter.

Comment: I agree with Günther, the principles for the application of inheritance remain the same in angular ergo typescript. The only special case that comes to my mind is injection by contract being archived through abstract class + concrete class instead of interface + concrete class as the usual case would be